# Trying to run psservice command in order to initiate windows service on a remote machine

Tags: java, cmd, rdp

I have this code which its purpose is to run service on a remote (windows) machine:

```
public void startProcessorDotNetService(){
        String currentServerHostname = "<remote_machine_ip>";
        String currentServerUser = "<user_name>";
        String currentServerPass="dyAf&E47p?s";
        String commandToStart="start serviceName";
        String commandToStop="stop serviceName";
        String psCommand ="<path_to_PSTools_directory>\\psservice \\\\"+ currentServerHostname + " -u " + currentServerUser + " -p " + currentServerPass;
        psCommandStart = psCommand + " " + commandToStart;
        psCommandStop = psCommand + " " + commandToStop;
        serviceStart();
    //    serviceStop();
    }

    private void serviceStart() {
        String[] command = {
                "cmd",
        };

        Process p;

        try{
            p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
            stdin.println(psCommandStart);

            stdin.close();
            p.waitFor();


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Now I noticed that if I'm running this command manually from the command prompt it cannot recognize the password as it is written and think by mistake that it is a command  `psservice \\[computer-IP] -u [user_name] -p dyAf&E47p?s start ServiceName`

I get the following error:

```
The user name or password is incorrect.
'E47p?s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I pass the password in a way it will be accepted?

Comment: The ampersand character is the problem; try to escape it like `dyAf^&E47p?s`; another way could be to put quotation marks `""` around it...

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this problem is to escaping the password in this manner:

"password" that will 'tell' the machine to look at it as non regular expression string.